# My Page is automatically Reloading when I click the dropdown button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just a newbie in javascript, I'm using a multiline forms and I can't find the reason why my page is reloading when I click the dropdown button and it keeps getting back on the first page of my form.

here is my code in the dropdown

```
 <div class="container3">
      <button class="click" name="drop" href="#">
        Select hours
      </button>
      <div class="list">
        <button class="links" href="#">6 Hours</button>
        <button class="links" href="#">8 Hours</button>
        <button class="links" href="#">10 Hours</button>
        <button class="links" href="#">16 Hours</button>
        <button class="links" href="#">20 Hours</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

here is the javascript:

```
 <script>
      let click = document.querySelector('.click');
      let list = document.querySelector('.list');
      click.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        list.classList.toggle('newlist');
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: first of all remove `href` and just add `type="button"` on your button tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove href property from `button` tags.

href is a property of `a` tag.

and if you want to cancel event of button add this to your code `event.preventDefault()`

here an example:

```
 <script>
      let click = document.querySelector('.click');
      let list = document.querySelector('.list');
      click.addEventListener("click", (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault()
        list.classList.toggle('newlist');
      });
 </script>
```

Comment: It works! highly appreciate it, thanks!